# Separately build Chromium Network stack on Windows10 with VS2017

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded, network-interface, network-service

I want to use just the network stack of the chromium in my project.

Could Anyone list the possible tutorials/steps to follow.
Or where can I get the documentation for the same.

I tried searching on Google but, no luck. The closest I get is this [link](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/component_build.md)

Comment: It's been a while Chromium uses clang, so it may not support VS.

Comment: I mean VS with clang-cl or the way cef builds